# playerItemDidReachEnd moves to wrong ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avplayer

My app has a start page and a second page with buttons that play videos. When a video is finished the AVPlayer is dismissed with playerItemDidReachEnd. But for some reason it shows the start page and not the second page when the player is dismissed. How can I get it to show the second page instead?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import AVKit;
@import AVFoundation;

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerItem *currentItem;
@end
@implementation ViewController

 AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
}


-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *) notification {
    //remove the player
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];    
    AVPlayer * player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect viewRect = mainScreen.bounds;
    playerViewController.view.frame = viewRect;
    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

       [player play];

    /* When the player item has played to its end time we'll dismiss the controller */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:playerViewController.player.currentItem];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, your "second page" is `ViewController`.

You are adding `AVPlayerViewController` by `[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];`, so you need to remove this view by calling 
`[playerViewController.view removeFromSuperview]`.

After `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`, you dismiss whole `ViewController`, not only `AVPlayerViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Michio. Not sure where to put the [playerViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; code?

Comment: Instead of `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`